# Product measure : difference between $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ and $\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the Lebesgue measure space $\mathscr M^1=(\mathbb R,\mathcal M,m)$. So, the Product space is given by $$\mathscr M^2=(\mathbb R^2, \mathcal M\times \mathcal M, m_2).$$

Even if $\mathscr M^1$ is complete, the space $\mathscr M^2$ is not complete. For instance, if $\mathcal N$ is the Vitali set, then $\{0\}\times \mathcal N$ is not in $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$. But I'm not really sure how to show that. My question are the following :

**1)** I know that $$\mathcal M\times \mathcal M=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}.$$
But do we have that $$\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\} \ \ ?$$
I guess it's not true (I can't find a counter example, do you have one ?)

**2)** So if $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M\neq \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$, an element $C\times D$ can be in $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ but neither $C$ nor $D$ is in $\mathcal M$. So how can I prove that $\{0\}\times \mathcal N\notin \mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ ?

Comment: An unsuccesful effort to *answer* your question inspired me to *ask* [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025386/169789) myself. Later I found an answer on it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is any set in $\mathbb R$ which is not Lebesgue measurable than $A\times \mathbb \{0\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal M \times \mathcal M$. [This is because its 'section' $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable]. But it is it is contained in $ \mathbb R \times \{0\}$ which has measure $0$.   This proves that the product measure is not complete.
In 2) you seem to assume that any set in the product is  a product set. That is not true. If you have  a product set $C\times D$ which belongs to the product sigma algebra then $C$ and $D$ necessarily belong to $\mathcal M$. [An example of a subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$ which is not of the form $C \times D$ is the diagonal $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:x=y\}$].

Comment: For 1), if it was true, then I could apply Fubini-Tonelli to $\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}\times A}(x,y)$ where $A$ is non measurable. So $\iint \boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}\times A}dxdy=0$ but by tonelli, $$\iint \boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}\times A}dxdy=\int_{\{0\}}\left(\int_A dy\right)dx$$ and the integral inside doesn't make sense... I don't get the point here.

Comment: In the french [wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Fubini) they say : *let $(A,\mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(B,\mathcal B, \nu)$ two $\sigma -$finite measure and let $(A\times B, \mathcal A\times \mathcal B, \nu\times \mu)$ the product measure. If $f:A\times B\to [0,\infty ]$ is $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B$ measurable then...* But $\{0\}\times A$ is $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ measurable, so tonelli should apply on $\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}\times A}$.

Comment: @NewMath I have edited my answer.

Comment: But this is all the question : It's not because $A$ or $B$ is not in $\mathcal M$ that $A\times B$ won't be in $\sigma \{C\times D\mid C,D\in \mathcal M\}$. So how can you prove that $\{0\}\times A$ not in $\sigma \{C\times D\mid C,D\in \mathcal M\}$ ? Just for example $[a,b[$ is not open but is in $\sigma \{U\subset \mathbb R\mid U\ open\}$... So, $A$ is indeed not in $\mathcal M$, but $\{0\}\times A$ could be in $\sigma \{C\times D\mid C,D\in \mathcal M\}$

Comment: @NewMath You have to look at the proof of Fubini's Theorem for this. In the beginning of the proof of this theorem (in Rudin's book, for example) it is shown that if a set $C$ in the product belongs to the product $\mathcal M \times \mathcal M$  then $\{x: (x,y) \in C\}$ is in $\mathcal M$ for each $y$ and $\{y: (x,y) \in C\}$ is in $\mathcal M$ for each $x$.