# If $A\times B$ is an element of a product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A\times\mathcal B$ then do we have $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on set $X$ and $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on set $Y$ then it is well known that $\mathcal A\times\mathcal B$ is the notation for a $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ that is generated by sets $A\times B$ with $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$.

So evidently we have: $$A\in\mathcal A\text{ and }B\in\mathcal B\implies A\times B\in\mathcal A\times\mathcal B\tag1$$

Now my question:

> Is the converse of $(1)$ also true?

I have always believed it is without bothering, but when I tried to find a proof for this "obvious" fact I regretfully failed.

Comment: thank you for asking the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately I found a proof for it myself after all.

---

Let $p_{1}:X\times Y\to X$ and $p_{2}:X\times Y\to Y$ be prescribed
by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto x$ and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto y$ respectively.

Characteristic for product space $\left(X\times Y,\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\right)$
is that for any measurable space $\left(Z,\mathcal{C}\right)$ and every function $f:Z\to X\times Y$ we have: $$f:Z\to X\times Y\text{ is measurable if and only if }p_{1}\circ f\text{ and
}p_{2}\circ f\text{ are both measurable}\tag1$$

The case is trivial if $B=\varnothing$ so let it be that $B\neq\varnothing$.

Now for some $y\in B$ let $u_{y}:X\to X\times Y$ be prescribed
by $x\mapsto\left(x,y\right)$.

Then based on $\left(1\right)$ we find easily that $u_{y}$ is measurable.

Then consequently $A=u_{y}^{-1}\left(A\times B\right)\in\mathcal{A}$.

Similarly it can be proved that $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: So at the end, $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B=\{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$... so why do we set $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$ ?

Comment: @NewMath No. We start with sets $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ and arrive at the conclusion that $A\in\mathcal A\text{ and }B\in\mathcal B\iff A\times B\in\mathcal A\times\mathcal B$. So we are **only** talking about subsets of $X\times Y$ that can be written as $A\times B$. The product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A\times\mathcal B$ also contains (lots of) sets that cannot be written like that.

Answer (score 1):

Both implications are true and they are proved in the beginning of Fubini's Theorem. For example you look at the discussion of 'sections' of measurable sets in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I do not have the disposal of Rudin, and actually I would like to say a proof of it on this site. Could you provide a link to the proof of Fubini's theorem maybe?

Comment: @Vera You can find a proof on Wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry, but the info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) about Fubini's theorem is not enough (for me) to provide in a proof. My question is still one that has not been answered yet.

Comment: I have answered my own question. Would you be so kind to check it, please? Thank you.

Comment: So at the end, $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B=\{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$... so why do we define $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$ ? Acctually, $\{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$ is a $\sigma -$algebra, no ? So $\sigma \{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}=\{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$ is straightforward... why we precise $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal A, B\in \mathcal B\}$ ? are there cases where it's wrong ?

Comment: @NewMath You are wrong.  $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:x=y\}$ belongs to $\mathcal B \times \mathcal B$ but it is of the form $A \times B$ for any sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't get your example... what do you mean by "it is of the form $A\times B$ for any set $A$ and $B$ ? It's really not clear...

Comment: If the set I have defined is $A \times B$ for some $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ then, for any real number $a$, $(a,a) \in A\times B$ so $a \in A$. Hence $A=\mathbb R$. Similarly, $B=\mathbb R$. But then $A \times B =\mathbb R^{2}$ which is  a contradiction because $(1,2)$ is not in my set.

Comment: I don't understand : So you message of the 4th december at 23:14 should be: *$\{(x,y)\mid x=y\}$ belong to $\mathcal B\times \mathcal B$ but it is **NOT** of the form $A\times B$ for any set $A$ and $B$*, no ?

Comment: @NewMath Yes, that is what I am saying.